# Element is appended but not shown in nextElementSibling [updated]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this program that can make closables dynamically. When the user clicks on a created closable an input box and a button are displayed in the content of the closable. The user can then input text into the textbox and then press the button. Then the users text will be displayed in the selected closable content.

Everything works, fine except for when I try to append the users input to the selected closable. I'm trying to append the users input with this function, but it doesn't work:

```
    var taskCounter = 0;
function addTask() {
  var text = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
  console.log(text);
  var newTask = $("<input type='checkbox'><label>"+ text + "</label><br>");
  newTask.id = 'temp' + taskCounter;
  console.log(newTask.id);
  taskCounter++
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

  $(currentContent).append(newTask); //where is it being append to??
  console.log("added") //it say it added but where?
}
```

Why isn't the users input being displayed in the selected closable? And if I'm not doing this correctly already, how do you append a dynamically created element to an elements nextElementSibling?

**Here is my full code:**

```js
var currentClosable;
var currentContent;
function selectedColl(){
 document.getElementById("inputTaskDiv").style.display = "block";
 currentClosable = event.target;
 currentContent = currentClosable.nextElementSibling;
 console.log(currentContent);
  var inputTaskDiv = document.getElementById("inputTaskDiv");
  currentContent.append(inputTaskDiv);
}

var taskCounter = 0;
function addTask() {
  var text = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newTask = $("<input type='checkbox'><label>"+ text + "</label><br>");
  newTask.id = 'temp' + taskCounter;
  taskCounter++
  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

  $(currentContent).append(newTask); //where is it being append to????
}

var elementCounter = 0;
var elementCounterContent = 0;
var text;
function addElement() {
  text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  
  var newDiv = $("<button class='collapsible' onclick='selectedColl()'></button>").text(text);
  var newContentOfDiv = $("<div class='content'></div>");


  newDiv.id = 'temp' + elementCounter;
  newContentOfDiv.id = 'content' + elementCounterContent;

  newDiv.classList = "div";
  elementCounter++
  elementCounterContent++
  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM

  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";
  $("body").append(newDiv, newContentOfDiv);

  newDiv.click(function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <input id="input" type="text"><button onclick="addElement()">Add</button>
     
   <div id="inputTaskDiv" style="display:none">
     <input id="taskInput" type="text"><button onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: I realize now that the div is actually appended to the selected closables content, it's just not displayed in it automatically, new question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65377184/element-is-appended-but-not-shown-in-nextelementsibling

Comment: Don't abandon questions, especially when they don't have any answers yet. The right thing would have been to edit the question.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the advice. I will do that next time!

Comment: I'm wondering why you have included jQuery and then decided to use almost none of it. All the event handling and DOM manipulation you're doing here can be done much easier, clearer and more conveniently with jQuery, your code could be half the size or less while still doing the same things or more - alternatively, the things you *did* use jQuery for could be done with vanilla JS and you could cut out the library altogether. It's a rather strange pairing you chose.