# Element is appended but not shown in nextElementSibling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this program that can make closables dynamically. When the user clicks on a created closable an input box and a button are displayed in the content of the closable. The user can then input text into the textbox and then press the button. Then the users text will be displayed in the selected closable content.

Everything works, fine, except for when I try to display the users input in the selected closables content.

**Here's what's happening:**

When the user inputs something in the text box it's append to the closables content:

[image]

The text is only displayed in the closable content after I close the selected closable:

[image]

Why isn't the users input being displayed in the selected closable after I click the add task button?

**Here is my full code:**

```js
var currentClosable;
var currentContent;
function selectedColl(){
 document.getElementById("inputTaskDiv").style.display = "block";
 currentClosable = event.target;
 currentContent = currentClosable.nextElementSibling;
  var inputTaskDiv = document.getElementById("inputTaskDiv");
  currentContent.append(inputTaskDiv);
}

var taskCounter = 0;
function addTask() {
  var text = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newTask = $("<input type='checkbox'><label>"+ text + "</label><br>");
  newTask.id = 'temp' + taskCounter;
  taskCounter++
  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

  $(currentContent).append(newTask); //Why isn't it being displayed??
  console.log("appended");
}

var elementCounter = 0;
var elementCounterContent = 0;
var text;
function addElement() {
  text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  
  var newDiv = $("<button class='collapsible' onclick='selectedColl()'></button>").text(text);
  var newContentOfDiv = $("<div class='content'></div>");


  newDiv.id = 'temp' + elementCounter;
  newContentOfDiv.id = 'content' + elementCounterContent;

  newDiv.classList = "div";
  elementCounter++
  elementCounterContent++
  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM

  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";
  $("body").append(newDiv, newContentOfDiv);

  newDiv.click(function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <input id="input" type="text"><button onclick="addElement()">Add</button>
     
   <div id="inputTaskDiv" style="display:none">
     <input id="taskInput" type="text"><button onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a problem with css not with the script! the problem is with `max-height`. if you omit that part it will work!

Comment: Yes it's indeed about CSS, `overflow: hidden` should be removed

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I tried both of your suggestions, removing max-height didn't change anything for me ... then I also tried to remover overflow: hidden but when i close the most recently created closable the content doesn't retract with the closable ...

Comment: @SaymoinSam I tried to remover overflow: hidden but when i close the most recently created closable the content doesn't retract with the closable

Comment: Regardless thank you for your help, I'll try to figure out to make it work with your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes made are in CSS and JS.

In CSS you can see which lines are commented on style ".content": `max-height` and `overflow`

The change in JS is:
I changed `content.style.maxHeight` with this `content.style.display`

```
this.classList.toggle("active");
content = this.nextElementSibling;
if (content.style.display === 'block') {
    content.style.display = 'none';
} else {
    content.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**Example:**

```js
var currentClosable;
var currentContent;
function selectedColl() {
    document.getElementById("inputTaskDiv").style.display = "block";
    currentClosable = event.target;
    currentContent = currentClosable.nextElementSibling;
    var inputTaskDiv = document.getElementById("inputTaskDiv");
    currentContent.append(inputTaskDiv);
}

var taskCounter = 0;
function addTask() {
    var text = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
    // create a new div element and give it a unique id
    var newTask = $("<input type='checkbox'><label>" + text + "</label><br>");
    newTask.id = 'temp' + taskCounter;
    taskCounter++
    // and give it some content
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

    $(currentContent).append(newTask); //Why isn't it being displayed??
    console.log("appended");
}

var elementCounter = 0;
var elementCounterContent = 0;
var text;
function addElement() {
    text = document.getElementById("input").value;
    // create a new div element and give it a unique id

    var newDiv = $("<button class='collapsible' onclick='selectedColl()'></button>").text(text);
    var newContentOfDiv = $("<div class='content'></div>");


    newDiv.id = 'temp' + elementCounter;
    newContentOfDiv.id = 'content' + elementCounterContent;

    newDiv.classList = "div";
    elementCounter++
    elementCounterContent++
    // and give it some content
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(text);

    // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM

    document.getElementById("input").value = " ";
    $("body").append(newDiv, newContentOfDiv);

    newDiv.click(function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === 'block') {
            content.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            content.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    /* max-height: 0; */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text"><button onclick="addElement()">Add</button>

<div id="inputTaskDiv" style="display:none">
    <input id="taskInput" type="text"><button onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
</div>
```